# Angular display conditional text in html including conditional data

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, angular-material, string-interpolation

I know in Angular2+ we can create condition in html like this:

```
  <p>{{ dynamicData.value? dynamicData.value : dynamicData.default}}</p>
```

Also we can do something like this:

```
  <p>{{ dynamicData.value? 'text 1' : 'text 2'}}</p>
```

But I would like to combine this two solutions and I have no idea how to do this. In general I would like to do something like this:

```
  <p>{{ dynamicData.value? 'Dynamic data value is equal: {{dynamicData.value}}' : 'no dynamic data'</p>
```

Have you any idea how to handle this text interpolation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need to use interpolation within interpolation, you already have access to variables and can try something as below:

```html
<p>{{ dynamicData?.value ? ('Dynamic data value is equal: ' + dynamicData?.value) : 'no dynamic data'}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<p *ngIf = "dynamicData.value"> 'Dynamic data value is equal' {{dynamicData.value}} </p>
<p *ngIf = "!dynamicData.value"> 'no dynamic data' </p>
```

Comment: I know this is one of available solutions but in my case i have *ngFor so can't use *ngIf. That is why i started wondering how solve it oher way.

Comment: Where have you *ngFor? on p tag?

Comment: Yes. Of course your answer is working and is more elegant but I was wondering how to handle this interpolation case.

Comment: You can wrap p in a div,  <div *ngFor=".."> <p.......</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable in your .ts file or you can use `+` interpolation `'Dynamic data value is equal: ' + dynamicData.default`.

But I like more answer posted by FedMice ;)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works.

```
 <p>{{ dynamicData.value ? (`Dynamic data value is equal: ${dynamicData?.value}`) : `no dynamic data`}}</p>
```